# Why is destructuring assignment used here? and what exactly is it doing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, destructuring

In the [Node JS Child Process documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), the following line is given in an example:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
```

Why is [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) assignment used here?  and what exactly is it doing?  Is this implying that `require('child_process')` returns an object with multiple elements, and 'spawn' is the first?  (I thought objects' elements were not in any guaranteed order?)

Comment: the `require()` returns an object, but `spawn` is property of that object, not necessarily the first. The property *name* is "spawn".

Comment: It's like `const x = require("child_process"); const spawn = x.spawn;`

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for clarifying.